# Intent dosen't work on ListView items. Class extends to ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

**I have a listView with custom adapter, my custom adapter contains buttons . 
i want to change activity when i click the buttons i do this:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChatActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**but it dosent work.**

**Here is my code:**

```
class CustomUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {

public CustomUserAdapter(Context context, List<String> usernames) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row_user, usernames);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_user, parent, false);

    String singleUser = getItem(position);
    Button bUser = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.bUserList);
    bUser.setText(singleUser);
    bUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    return customView;
}
```

}

Comment: your button onclick is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your new Activity with the help of context like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,ChatActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
   private Context  _Contaxt;
   public CustomUserAdapter(Context context, List<String> usernames) {
  super(context, R.layout.custom_row_user, usernames);
    this._Contaxt=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_user, parent, false);

String singleUser = getItem(position);
Button bUser = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.bUserList);
bUser.setText(singleUser);
bUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(_Contaxt,ChatActivity.class);
     _Contaxt.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

return customView;
  }
 }
```